# C++ declare class variable outside of "if-else"

Tags: c++, overloading

Is it possible to declare class variable outside of "if-else" and initialize it inside the "if-else"?

something like this:

```
myClass mc;
if (bOOlVar){
  mc(10);
}
else{
  mc(10,20);
}
```

assuming I have 2 cons' for myClass(one that receives int and one that receives 2 ints)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
auto mc = (boolVar? MyClass( 10 ) : MyClass( 10, 20 ));
```

Comment: Actually never thought of this one. I like it.

Comment: Just as a note, only works for movable types. You have to do some hijinks to make it work in-place.

Comment: @DeadMG: no, not quite. in practice copying/moving will be optimized away (permission to do such *copy/move elision* is granted by C++11 §12.8/31), but the standard still requires an accessible copy or move constructor.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. The close which is possible is this:

```
myClass mc(10);
if (!bOOlVar)
{
  mc = myClass(10,20); //if assignment is allowed
}
```